# Return top N buckets only

Tags: elasticsearch

So in elastic search I can do something like this:

```
{
"aggs": {
    "title": {
        "terms": {
            "field": "title",
            "shard_size": 50,
            "size": 5
        }
    }
},
"query": {...},
"size": 0
```

}

And this will return me the document counts of the top 5 titles, so we end up with something like (in part):

```
"buckets" : [
    {
      "key" : "Delivery Driver",
      "doc_count" : 1495
    },
    {
      "key" : "Assistant Manager",
      "doc_count" : 1250
    },
    {
      "key" : "Server",
      "doc_count" : 1175
    },
    {
      "key" : "Dishwasher",
      "doc_count" : 966
    },
    {
      "key" : "Team Member",
      "doc_count" : 960
    }
  ]
```

But now I need to have the document counts in some custom buckets, so I do something like this:

```
{
    "aggs": {
        "loc": {
            "filters": {
                "filters": {
                    "1042_2": {
                        "terms": {
                            "counties": [
                                ...
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    "1594_2": {
                        "terms": {
                            "counties": [
                                ...
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    "1714_2": {
                        "terms": {
                            "counties": [
                                ...
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    "1746_2": {
                        "terms": {
                            "counties": [
                                ...
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    "1814_2": {
                        "terms": {
                            "counties": [
                                ...
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    "1943_2": {
                        "terms": {
                            "counties": [
                                ...
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    "2658_2": {
                        "terms": {
                            "counties": [
                                ...
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "query": {...},
    "size": 0
}
```

Note that there are 7 buckets, because we don't know which are the largest. Running this will return us:

```
"buckets" : {
    "1042_2" : {
      "doc_count" : 23687
    },
    "1594_2" : {
      "doc_count" : 8951
    },
    "1714_2" : {
      "doc_count" : 52555
    },
    "1746_2" : {
      "doc_count" : 60534
    },
    "1814_2" : {
      "doc_count" : 63956
    },
    "1943_2" : {
      "doc_count" : 25533
    },
    "2658_2" : {
      "doc_count" : 534
    }
  }
```

But I would like it to *only* return me the largest 5 instead of all the buckets. Is there a way to restrict it to only the *n* largest buckets in the same way that the `size` parameter under `terms` did?

Answer (score 0):

The `size` parameter does not make sense for filters aggregation, because by specifying the filters you already explicitly specify/control the number of buckets to get created and returned.

What you may want to consider though is, that you get all potential buckets created, but then get them sorted by descending count with an `order`-clause.

On client side then you simply "consume" the first `n` buckets.

Comment: Well that's what I'm doing on the client side, and in the case in the question, it's not a huge deal. But in other case there could be many buckets, maybe in the hundreds, so it would be nice if there was a more efficient way to only get the largest back from elastic.